# PHP local setup / only ever coded live

Tags: php

I've only ever coded to a live web server (well using a test domain and then transferring to the live one).

I actually know a decent amount of PHP, just never coded locally.

- I want to also set up, learn and use Symfony2.
- I also want access to the command line (as I know Symfony 2 requires this to set up bundles etc.)
- I also know people integrate this with Github.
- I'm using a Mac OS X 10.8.2.
- I want to use Apache as the web server.

I understand everybody codes 'locally'. How do I set all this up? Maybe just a list of all the things I need. This is my rough understanding so far:

(1) Get http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html

(2) Get Composer (not sure what for though)

(3) Symfony2 download

What about command line access though?

Comment: Terminal is your command line (http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/getting-command-line-access-php-and-mysql-running-mamp-osx). Composer makes it easy to install Symfony and dependencies that your system may not have.

Comment: Thanks, so that;s Terminal on the Mac and if so, do commands refer to the local file (e.g. documents/symfony/folder/file etc.) or does it refer to a remote location? (I see local host used a lot)

Comment: I use VirtualBox with an Ubuntu installation to mess around with a LAMP setup (running on my win7 laptop). This virtualisation is easy to backup or move to other machines, you get command line and everything you need. Also, the support for Ubuntu is huge :)

Answer (score 0):

Here a bit more info:

Installing Composer locally.

1) edit or create ~/.bash_profile

2) add this to edit (change to correct php version):

alias phpmamp='/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/php'

3) Refresh terminal bash:

. .bash_profile

4) Install Composer using:

curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | phpmamp

phpmamp is your PHP installed by MAMP